# training spaCy for a specific sentence

Tags: spacy

How do I train spaCy to do appropriate dependency tagging for a single sentence like "children like chocolates".

spaCy currently marks the dependency for "children","like","chocolates" as ROOT, PREP and POBJ respectively,  while the correct marking would be SUB, ROOT and DOBJ respectively.